# Mysql error not following where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, where-clause

Why is this sql giving tables with `minimum` field having null. Also when `A` has no data between the given date ranges, it is providing the table with all `rooms` having `minimum` as null

```
   SELECT `rooms`.*,A.`minimum`
    FROM (
        SELECT `room_id`, min(`available_rooms`) AS `minimum`
        FROM `room_bookings` 
        WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-10' 
        GROUP BY `room_id`) as A
    INNER JOIN `rooms` on `rooms`.`room_id`=A.`room_id` 
    WHERE `rooms`.`location`='kathmandu' 
    AND `rooms`.`status`=1 
    AND A.`minimum`!=NULL
```

Comment: replace `AND A.minimum !=NULL` with `AND A.minimum is not NULL`. null checks need to use the `IS` operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT r.*, MIN(rb.available_rooms) minimum 
FROM rooms r 
INNER JOIN room_bookings rb ON r.room_id = rb.room_id AND rb.date BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-10' 
WHERE r.location = 'kathmandu' AND r.status = 1 
GROUP BY r.room_id HAVING minimum IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: also is there any way where we can put `r.total_rooms` to the `minimum` when `minimum` is null??

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT `rooms`.*,A.`minimum`
    FROM (
        SELECT `room_id`, min(`available_rooms`) AS `minimum`
        FROM `room_bookings` 
        WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-10' 
        GROUP BY `room_id` having minimum > 0) as A
    INNER JOIN `rooms` on `rooms`.`room_id`=A.`room_id` 
    WHERE `rooms`.`location`='kathmandu' 
    AND `rooms`.`status`=1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `rooms`.*,A.`minimum`
FROM (
    SELECT `room_id`, min(`available_rooms`) AS `minimum`
    FROM `room_bookings` 
    WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-10' 
    GROUP BY `room_id`) as A
INNER JOIN `rooms` on `rooms`.`room_id`=A.`room_id` 
WHERE `rooms`.`location`='kathmandu' 
AND `rooms`.`status`=1 
AND A.`minimum` is not NULL
```

This would be the correct syntax ( change `!=` to `is not` )

Answer (score 1):

try this with IS NOT NULL

```
SELECT `rooms`.*,A.`minimum`
    FROM (
        SELECT `room_id`, min(`available_rooms`) AS `minimum`
        FROM `room_bookings` 
        WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-10' 
        GROUP BY `room_id`) as A
    INNER JOIN `rooms` on `rooms`.`room_id`=A.`room_id` 
    WHERE `rooms`.`location`='kathmandu' 
    AND `rooms`.`status`=1 
    AND A.`minimum` IS NOT NULL
```